# What does an empty parenthesis "()" in logging config dictionary mean?

Tags: python, logging, logstash

I am playing around with the [Python Logstash Formatter](https://github.com/exoscale/python-logstash-formatter) and [in its wiki](https://github.com/exoscale/python-logstash-formatter/wiki/Configuration-and-making-it-work-in-Python) it recommended setting the following option for the formatter:

```
"formatters": { "logstash":{ "()": "logstash_formatter.LogstashFormatter" } }
```

This is working for me, but I'm unsure of what the empty parentheses are for, or what exactly `logstash_formatter.LogstashFormatter` is being set to in this example.

Can someone explain to me what the empty parentheses mean here in relation to the Python logger? It almost seems like it would be an empty tuple, except I can't fathom how setting an empty tuple to a class would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check out the [python docs for logging](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects), you'll see this:

> Objects to be configured are described by dictionaries which detail their configuration. In some places, the logging system will be able to infer from the context how an object is to be instantiated, but when a user-defined object is to be instantiated, the system will not know how to do this. In order to provide complete flexibility for user-defined object instantiation, the user needs to provide a ‘factory’ - a callable which is called with a configuration dictionary and which returns the instantiated object. This is signalled by an absolute import path to the factory being made available under the special key `'()'`.

Basically what it means is that `logstash_formatter.LogstashFormatter` is the factory that is going to create a new formatter. So when the logging framework would like to create a formatter, it's going to make sure to `import logstash_formatter` and then do something like `logstash_formatter.LogstashFormatter(*args, **kwargs)`.

Indeed, if you [use the source, Luke](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/logging/config.py#L646), you can see that

- [The value is extracted](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/logging/config.py#L459)
- [Then resolved/imported](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/logging/config.py#L370)
- And [the created factory is used here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/logging/config.py#L370)

  ```
  if '()' in config:
      factory = config['()'] # for use in exception handler
  ```
- [And later the factory is called with kwargs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/logging/config.py#L731):

  ```
      result = factory(**kwargs)
  ```

Comment: Arg I somehow missed this when I read through the logging docs. Thanks!

Comment: I found it when I went to the logging config page and searched for `()` :)

Comment: Lol well when you search `()` you also get empty function declarations. I was particularly perturbed yesterday so i probably was just impatient

Comment: You could also try adding `'()'` or `"()"` (typically Python docs will use the preferred form (`repr`) of a thing. If you want to know what that is, `>>> repr("()")` will show you `'()'`.